# Title view and uinavigationLargeTitleVIew are overlapping

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11

Title view and uinavigationLargeTitleVIew are overlapping when I press back button to come back to this view
[image]

Comment: Try giving constraint to titleView. Refer my answer  for more details, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830649/how-can-i-fix-the-navigationbar-title-position-in-ios11

Comment: i fixed this issue by hiding status bar and using a custom view