# How can I fix the navigationbar title position in ios11

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11, navigationbar

Here is the code

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`viewController` is a `UIImagePickerController`

When I presented in `viewController`, `navigationbar` title shifted.

Please check the image.

[image: I'm the image]

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method to customize and change navigation bar button

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
          //---> Code
 }
```

For more info seen the following link:
[Link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17831-change-cancel-button-title-in-uiimagepickercontroller.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a constraint to titleView, from iOS11 navigation bar is playing with constraint instead of frames like before so,

```
public extension UIView {
//From iOS 11 -> UIBarButtonItem uses autolayout instead of dealing with frames. so adding contraint for the barbuttonItem
public func applyNavBarConstraints(size: (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let widthConstraint = self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        let heightConstraint = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}}
```

and use this as below:

```
navigationItem.titleView.applyNavBarConstraints(size: (width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))
```

Hope this helps!